# sublime-text 2 ftpsync ignore not working

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

In my yii project on windows 7 I have the following structure:

```
/project
.. /yii
.... /framework
.... /protected
.... ftpsync.settings
```

in ftpsync.settings I want to ignore the framework folder as the following:

```
"ignore": "\\\\framework\\\\"
```

then in sidebar when I right click on yii folder > FTPSync > Upload, then it should ignore the framework folder which is not happening

so any ideas please?

Comment: What do you mean by *it's not working*? What do you expect would happen? What's happening instead? describe your problem in details please.

Comment: thanks for comment, I've updated the question with more explanation.

Comment: From the documentation - `Then it will try to look in current and all parent folders in a path whether they contain ftpsync.settings file until the nearest is found (or ends up with none).` I think you should have the ftpsync.settings file at the root of the project. your ignore value looks good. Might be that the file is not found.

Comment: I have **ftpsync.settings** in yii folder and I've tried to put it in root project folder and still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"ignore": "\\\\framework\\\\"
```

**is working** but I was confused when I see the number of all files in the status bar